# Illegal Syntax. Expected valid start name character

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Not sure whats gone wrong here, not very good at this stuff so apologise in advance. Ive got the below but faulting when trying to run. Not sure whats gone wrong with this part as used to work before on an older server and migrated the data across.

```
<%
rs.Close
if request.form  () <> "" then
varSearch = replace(request.form("T1"),"*","%")
varSearch = replace(varSearch," ","%")
sql = "SELECT * FROM [Cards] WHERE [CardTypeID] = 'C' AND [Name] LIKE '%" & varSearch & "%'
ORDER BY [Name]"
rs.Source = sql
rs.Open
%>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's the error message you get?

Comment: Have you turned `Option Explicit` on at the beginning of your code?  I would recommend you do this if you haven't already.  Also, does your SQL *actually* break over the line in your code?  If it does, then that could be your problem.

Comment: Please show the exact error message. Which line is raising it? And how exactly do you "try to run" the code?

Comment: Hi sorry just saw these comments now. If I try run i get the following.

Comment: Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80004005' 

Disk or network error.

Comment: Yes Option Explicit is turned on.

Answer (score 0):

`request.form()` - you're not capturing anything

```
<%
rs.Close
if request.form  ("T1") <> "" then
varSearch = replace(request.form("T1"),"*","%")
varSearch = replace(varSearch," ","%")
sql = "SELECT * FROM [Cards] WHERE [CardTypeID] = 'C' AND [Name] LIKE '%" & varSearch & "%'
ORDER BY [Name]"
rs.Source = sql
rs.Open
%>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for help with this, but sadly still didnt fix it :(